# Formatting issues with rest service json output

Tags: java, json, api, restful-url

My below java code returns the following output.

```
public String getAttributeMaster_2() throws JsonProcessingException {       
    Cluster cluster = couchBaseConnectionManager.openBucketOfActivCluster(CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan);
    Map<String,Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    attributeMap.put("Product_Brand", attributeMasterRepository.getProductBrand(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));   
    attributeMap.put("Product_Type", attributeMasterRepository.getProductType(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    attributeMap.put("Product_Event", attributeMasterRepository.getProductEvent(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    String attribute = attributeMap.toString();

    return attribute;

}
```

Output:

```
{"Product_Type"=[{"active":true,"description":"ACCESSORIES","id":1}, {"active":true,"description":"ALL IN ONES","id":2}], "Product_Brand"=[{"active":false,"description":"101 DALMATIANS","id":1}], "Product_Event"=[{"description":"BABY EVENT","id":2}, {"description":"ACTIVE EVENT","id":1}]}
```

Expected output:

```
{"Product_Type":[{"active":true,"description":"ACCESSORIES","id":1}, {"active":true,"description":"ALL IN ONES","id":2}], "Product_Brand":[{"active":false,"description":"101 DALMATIANS","id":1}], "Product_Event":[{"description":"BABY EVENT","id":2}, {"description":"ACTIVE EVENT","id":1}]}
```

Issue:
I want the to replace =(equals) sign with :(colon).

For Ex: Product_Type as "Product_Type". Same is the case with Product_Brand and Product_Event.

Please let me know if someone can help me achieve this.

I am new to java coding. Appreciate your response.

Thanks,

Comment: I have no clue of what libraries you are using to parse json, but since your code has reached a point where you can use getProductBrand for "Product_Type", if would be simpler to check if exists or not by checking the length of string it returns, or weather it returns null or weather it throws an exception.

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo Im able to get the output. the only thing I have issue is with the name(Product_Type) as in the output coming without double quotes(""). Could you please let me know what am I missing here? I want to get Product_Type as "Product_Type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the keys in attributeMap adding any value apart from generating the string representation returned by attributeMap.toString().

In this case, you can simply escape and add double quotes for the keys, like so:

```
Map<String,Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
attributeMap.put("\"Product_Brand\"", ...);
attributeMap.put("\"Product_Type\"", ...);
attributeMap.put("\"Product_Event\"", ...);

String attribute = attributeMap.toString();
```

Comment: I have = sign in the output, which needs to be changed to :.

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes soulds work :

```
public String getAttributeMaster_2() throws JsonProcessingException {       
    Cluster cluster = couchBaseConnectionManager.openBucketOfActivCluster(CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan);
    Map<String,Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    attributeMap.put("\Product_Brand\"", attributeMasterRepository.getProductBrand(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));   
    attributeMap.put("\"Product_Type\"", attributeMasterRepository.getProductType(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    attributeMap.put("\"Product_Event\"", attributeMasterRepository.getProductEvent(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
String attribute = attributeMap.toString();

return attribute;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may use an json lib, like net.sf.json.JSONObject

```
 import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
 public String getAttributeMaster_2(){
    Cluster cluster = couchBaseConnectionManager.openBucketOfActivCluster(CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("Product_Brand", "");
    jsonObject.put("Product_Brand", attributeMasterRepository.getProductBrand(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    jsonObject.put("Product_Type", attributeMasterRepository.getProductType(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    jsonObject.put("Product_Event", attributeMasterRepository.getProductEvent(cluster, CouchbaseBucket.RangePlan));
    String attribute = jsonObject.toString();
}
```